# How to estimate the cost of exporting Firebase Performance Monitoring to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am planning to export Firebase Performance Monitoring (FPM) data to BigQuery for analysis, using the following as a reference

https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/bigquery-export?hl=ja

What are the specific steps and best practices to estimate the costs involved? I am a novice when it comes to BigQuery...

I am looking forward to an answer from anyone who is kind enough to help.

Comment: Please check the pricing [document mentioned](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/bigquery-export?hl=en#pricing). Once your data resides in BigQuery you will pay for the storage and query compute power. You can estimate the cost with [GCP pricing calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator?hl=en)